# batch file breaks when checking if a variable is defined

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file to locate a program's install directory.

```
CALL:get_vsinstalldir InstallDir
echo InstallDir="%InstallDir%"

EXIT /B 0

@REM get the location of the visual studio 2012 installation
:get_vsinstalldir
FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%A IN ('REG.EXE QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config" /V "ShellFolder" 2^>NUL ^| FIND "REG_SZ"') DO SET %~1=%%B
EXIT /B 0
```

This works fine and outputs something like `InstallDir="C:\path to VS\blah"`

But, if I check to see if the `InstallDir` is already defined like this:

```
if not defined InstallDir (
    CALL:get_vsinstalldir InstallDir
    echo InstallDir="%InstallDir%"
)
```

Then, it prints `InstallDir=""`

Why is the `if not defined` statement breaking my batch file?

Comment: The brackets `(` and `)` cause everything inside them to be evaluated straight away, so `InstallDir` is being evaluated before it is set.  Search for "delayed evaluation" to see one solution, or use goto rather than brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enabling delayed expansion, put `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` at first line, then use exclamation points to verify it's defined or no:

```
    if not defined InstallDir (
     CALL:get_vsinstalldir InstallDir
     echo InstallDir="!InstallDir!"
    )
```